# Dynamically position elements in a horizontal linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Using Android API 10. I have a scenario where I need to dynamically add views to a horizontal `LinearLayout`. The layout should support 0-3 views, between views there should be a 1px vertical divider. If no view is added a placeholder text should be added in the center of the layout. The views should be centered in the layout

```
 View | View | View
```

So I need a way to update this dynamically with a `List<View>`

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you created a layout?

Comment: I'm downvoting because no current code or other current efforts have been provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the following method should do what you want. We simply set the appropriate `LayoutParams` for each child of the `LinearLayout`, creating divider `View`s as needed. If the `List` of `View`s is empty, a placeholder `TextView` is created and added instead. It should work for any number of `View`s.

```
private void populateLayout(LinearLayout layout, List<View> views) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    int numViews = views.size();

    layout.removeAllViews();

    if (numViews == 0) {
        TextView placeholder = new TextView(layout.getContext());
        placeholder.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        placeholder.setText("Placeholder");

        lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        layout.addView(placeholder, lp);
    }
    else {
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            1);

        for (int i = 0; i < numViews; i++) {
            layout.addView(views.get(i), lp);

            if (numViews - i > 1) {
                View divider = new View(layout.getContext());
                divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                layout.addView(divider,
                               new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                   1,
                                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }
        }
    }
}
```